# Setting Geopandas plot's labels

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, geopandas

I have a raster data which contains 40 band total. Here is the head of my data:

[image]

So I created a code that can read and calculate the mean of the bands like this:

```
prof = train_pts.groupby (['classes']).mean ()
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (17,20))
band_n = [ 'Band [2,6,11,16]', 'Band [3,7,12,17]', 'Band [4,8,13,30]', 'Band [20,22,14,26]', 'Band [2,26,11,30]', 'Band [2,26,11,30]']
band_name = ['Sentinel-2 B2'], ['Sentinel-2 B3']
n = 1
for ba in band_n :
    ax = fig.add_subplot(4,2,n)
    ax.title.set_text(band_name)
    band_val = prof[prof.columns[prof.columns.to_series().str.contains(ba)]]
    for index, row in band_val.iterrows():
        color = cmap (index)
        ax.plot (row,color=color)
        ax.autoscale(enable=True, axis="both", tight=None)
    ax.set_xticklabels([(str (band_name) for band_name in range(1, len(row)+1))])
    ax.legend(loc='best', fontsize='small', ncol=2, labels=class_names)
    n=n+1
```

For example, for Sentinel-2 B2 it calculates the mean of these bands for each point and plot them. But I am struggling with x, y axis labels and the title of the plots. What I wanted to do here is set the `'Band [2,6,11,16]'` plot's label as '`Sentinel-2 B2'`, `'Band [3,7,12,17]'` plot's label as `['Sentinel-2 B3']` and go on like this... But it write the same title for all plots that I created. Like this:

[image]

What can I try else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, band name never changes:

```py
band_name = ['Sentinel-2 B2'], ['Sentinel-2 B3']
n = 1
for ba in band_n :
    ax = fig.add_subplot(4,2,n)
    ax.title.set_text(band_name)  # this is unaffected by the loop
```

I think you mean something along these lines... making use of the [enumerate built in function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)

```py
band_name = ['Sentinel-2 B2', 'Sentinel-2 B3']
for i, ba in enumerate(band_n):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(4,2,i + 1)
    ax.title.set_text(band_name[i])
```

But you don't have enough band_names for the number of bands, so you'll need to fix your `band_name` list before this code will work.

Comment: Yes, now it works. But now I get an error message below the plots that says 'generator object genexpr' something like this. And I couldn't set the y axis, unfortunately

Comment: ok. that sounds like a different issue though. I'd recommend stepping through the code line by line and understanding what's happening to the objects you're working with. Without your data, I can't anticipate everything that might go wrong as you edit your code. Check out these guides to debugging in [pycharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/part-1-debugging-python-code.html#start-debugger-session) and [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging)